# Que dit-on lorsqu'on commande de la nourriture et que l'on doit choisir où on mangera ?

Tags: expressions, usage, régionalismes, alimentation, travail

Je suis serveur dans un café au Canada.

Lorsque je sers un client, je dois poser une question afin de savoir si le client mange/boit au café ou s'il quitte le café avec son café et sa nourriture. Le café n'est pas comme un restaurant (les clients commandent et payent au comptoir).

Au Québec, on dirait : « *C'est pour emporter ou pour ici ?* »

Mais au Nouveau-Brunswick (la variété acadienne), on pourrait dire : « *C'est pour sortir ou pour ici ?* »

Que dirait-on en France ?

J'apprécierais d'autres exemples pour différentes régions de France et même différents pays (s'il existe d'autres expressions).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En France, on utilisera "*Sur place ou à emporter?*". Je pense que la même expression est utilisée en Belgique aussi.

Cependant, en Suisse romande, beaucoup de monde utilise "*Sur place ou à l'emporter?*" (noter le ***l'*** avant *emporter*)

Comment: “À l’emporter”, “à l’emporté” ou “à l‘emportée” ?

Comment: @Édouard "A l'emporter", comme [ici](http://www.restaurantchezchou.ch/plats-a-lemporter-26-pa-fr), [là](http://www.lefrascati.ch/carte_takeaway.php?id=1) ou encore [là-bas](http://www.indigo-geneve.com/index.php?id=3)

Answer (score 7):

En France, on demande le plus souvent "*Sur place ou à emporter ?*". Mais s'en tenir à "*(Consommez-vous) sur place ?*" est également très bien compris.

Je ne connais pas de régionalismes particuliers.